¿Como puedo ordenar una matriz de 3x10 con Bubble Sort en python?
Tengo una arreglo bidimensional de 3x10 y quiero ordenarlo con bubble sort pero no he podido y no se donde esta el detalle.
Mi codigo:
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rand_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        fila = []
        for j in range(10):
            fila.append(random.randint(0,100))
        rand_list.append(fila)

    print('\n LISTA DE NUMEROS ALEATORIOS')
    print(rand_list)
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")

    def burbuja(array):
        obj_num = len(array)
        for i in range(obj_num-1):
            for j in range(obj_num-1-i):
                if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
    
    burbuja(rand_list)
    print('ORDENAMIENTO BURBUJA')
    print(rand_list, "\n")

Ese código me devuelve lo siguiente

Lo que estoy buscando es que ordene los números de las 3 filas pero no lo hace.
Tambien ya intente pasarle el valor de 'fila' directo al bubble sort pero sólo ordena la ultima fila

¿Quieres ordenar cada fila independientemente o toda la matriz en su conjunto? Es decir, en el caso de una de 2x2 como [[7, 4], [5, 1]] la salida seria [[4, 7], [1, 5]] ó [[1, 4], [5, 7]]?

El problema principal radica en cómo estás aplicando el algoritmo de ordenamiento burbuja en una matriz 3x10. La implementación actual solo intercambia elementos dentro de una sola fila, pero no tiene en cuenta la estructura bidimensional de la matriz. Aquí tienes una forma de corregir eso:
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rand_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        fila = []
        for j in range(10):
            fila.append(random.randint(0, 100))
        rand_list.append(fila)

    print('\n LISTA DE NUMEROS ALEATORIOS')
    for fila in rand_list:
        print(fila)
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")

    def burbuja(matriz):
        for fila in matriz:
            obj_num = len(fila)
            for i in range(obj_num - 1):
                for j in range(obj_num - 1 - i):
                    if fila[j] > fila[j + 1]:
                        fila[j], fila[j + 1] = fila[j + 1], fila[j]

    burbuja(rand_list)
    print('ORDENAMIENTO BURBUJA')
    for fila in rand_list:
        print(fila)
    print("\n")

El resultado:
python3 test.py                

 LISTA DE NUMEROS ALEATORIOS
[14, 97, 37, 34, 82, 71, 96, 72, 98, 44]
[7, 72, 32, 78, 5, 50, 58, 67, 73, 57]
[10, 71, 3, 1, 35, 51, 14, 26, 35, 73]
------------------------------------------------------------------- 

ORDENAMIENTO BURBUJA
[14, 34, 37, 44, 71, 72, 82, 96, 97, 98]
[5, 7, 32, 50, 57, 58, 67, 72, 73, 78]
[1, 3, 10, 14, 26, 35, 35, 51, 71, 73]

Nota: El código te sirve para ordenar matrices de cualquier dimensión, solamente cambia el número de filas y columnas en las lineas 5 y 7
